# What is the best way to determine if a System.DateTime is midnight?

Tags: .net

It seems that there are several possible ways to determine if a given System.DateTime represents midnight. What are the pros and cons of each? Is one more readable or perform better than the others?

EDIT: I believe that readability is more important than performance until profiling shows that there is an issue. That is why I asked about both.

Example 1

```
Public Function IsMidnight(ByVal value As Date) As Boolean
    Return value.TimeOfDay = TimeSpan.FromHours(0)
End Function
```

Example 2

```
Public Function IsMidnight(ByVal value As Date) As Boolean
    Return value.CompareTo(value.[Date]) = 0
End Function
```

Comment: My examples are in VB.NET since that is what I am currently using professionally. However, this question is applicable to all languages in the .NET Framework.

Comment: For those curious about the usage, I am checking for DateTimes entered by date fields vs. those entered by date time fields.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I'd check (using C# for the example):

```
bool isMidnight = value.TimeOfDay.Ticks == 0;
```

IMO, this is easier than using `FromHours` etc, and doesn't involve any extra multiplication (since `Ticks` *defined* the `TimeSpan` - all the other properties are calculated).

Comment: I'd think that the ticks measurement would hardly ever evaluate to true. Executing a couple of statements would involve a few ticks.Might be easier to check for minutes.

Comment: It would evaluate to true for all the times that represent *true* midnight. You wouldn't call it on `DateTime.Now`, obviously, but it does the job as stated...

Comment: More importantly, it exactly matches the "Return value.TimeOfDay = TimeSpan.FromHours(0)" from the original question. Checking for minutes etc **doesn't**

Comment: @Cerebrus, see the comments on my answer.  OP is looking for exactly midnight down to the tick

Comment: @Cerebrus, whether or not that is a good approach though is contextual.  For actual captured times, probably not. But if the user is entering times or filtering is ocurring it may be perfectly OK

Answer (score 8):

This is a bit of micro-optimizing, either method would work fine.

Anyhow, I think this is what would perform best:

```
Public Function IsMidnight(ByVal value As Date) As Boolean
   Return value.TimeOfDay.Ticks = 0
End Function
```

If you want understandable code, perhaps this is best:

```
Public Function IsMidnight(ByVal value As Date) As Boolean
   Return value.TimeOfDay = TimeSpan.Zero
End Function
```

Comment: Actually, those should perform more or less equally, since Ticks is used as an internal value in TimeSpan. So (timespan == timespan) is more or less the same as (timespan.ticks == timespan.ticks) which in both cases will be (timespan.ticks == 0)

Comment: Yes, the == operator is implemented to compare the Ticks properties, so TimeSpan.Zero.Ticks is just a longer route to get to zero. :)

Answer (score 6):

Depends.  Do you want to check for exactly midnight to the second, or just that it's the midnight hour?

For the midnight hour

```
Public Function IsMidnightHour(ByVal date as Date) As Boolean
  return date.Hour = 0
End Function
```

For midnight hour and minute

```
Public Function IsMidnightHourAndMinute(ByVal date as Date) As Boolean
  return date.Hour = 0 AndAlso date.Minute = 0
End Function
```

For purely simply, exactly midnight you can use your example.  However that will include checks up to the millisecond which may not be what you want.

Comment: I am looking for exactly midnight to the millisecond.

Comment: @Eric, then Marc's answer is the most efficient way.

Comment: Often you only want to check the HH:mm part. Is it 0 hours and 0 minutes ? Midnight.